# Switch layout for checkbox failing in IE/Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, checkbox, input, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to get a css switch for checkboxes to work. An example can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWCNHR9N3EYO

The switch with two input elements inside the label element does not work on ie/edge. As this code is generated, I can't change this order of the elements. But there must be a css statement that ie/edge interprets different from other browsers.

This works on ie/edge:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

This does not work in ie/edge:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

How can I fix this?

Important: The order of the HTML elements cannot be changed as it automatically generated.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
Roberto

Comment: There is generic CSS for *input*. You need to make that more specific if you want to use 2 input fields

Comment: What is the reason for using two inputs? Can you delete one of them with JavaScript?

Comment: @Gerard I scoped the css to checkbox typed inputs in this example, still does not work though: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWCOVHLCTIIF

Comment: @Katana314 Unfortunately I can't change the structure of the HTML or remove the other input tag :(

Comment: @RobertoVasquezAngel That answered *one* of my questions.

Comment: A little bit of background info: This code is being developed for a rails application. Rails - by default - uses a hidden input to provide a value in the params hash even if the checkbox is not checked. This is behaviour i don't want/can't change without surprising other people.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **input** after **span class** like below may solve your issue.

```html
<label class="switch"> 
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <span class="slider"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</label>
```

By this way it is working in both IE and Edge.

You can make a test on your side that it is working as per your requirement or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the structure of the html. :(